# Dependent picklists not working in VF Component

Tags: visualforce-component, dependent-picklist

I have a VF page which uses a custom controller `SearchController`.
The VF page a has component `TempCmp`.
In the component `TempCmp`, I am trying to use dependent picklists using `apex:inputField`.

It throws the following error:

> The dependent picklist '**Dependent Pick List**' requires its controlling
>   field '**Controlling Pick list 1**' to be present on the page.

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="SearchController">
    This is page    
    <c:TempCmp leadVariable="{!patient}"></c:TempCmp>    
</apex:page>
```

**Custom Controller:**

```
global with sharing class SearchController { 
    public Lead patient  {get; set;}
}
```

**Component**:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="leadVariable" description="Object Variable" type="Lead"  />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!leadVariable.Controlling_Pick_list_1__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!leadVariable.Dependent_Pick_List__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:component>
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue using VF component?

Comment: on change of Controlling_Pick_list_1__c rerender the Dependent_Pick_List__c it's parent component then it reflect on VF page

Comment: The VF page throws the error on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be initialize the Lead ***patient*** object in **SearchController** , because of that your facing the issue.

```
global with sharing class SearchController { 
        public Lead patient  {get; set;}
        public SearchController () {
        patient = new lead();
        }
 }
```